# Problems with responsive scroll & height

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So i've been sitting with this, going back and forth for a while now trying to figure this one out. **Below is the bootply**

I am building a cart in which slides out: [image: My cart slider]

At the bottom of the cart there is this fixed bottom and above it the products. I created a div that was scrollable in order to fit the products, which works. However, it gets tricky when i'm trying to make it responsive. It is still scrollable, but its unstable and works really bad in the phone while in desktop it works good. What am i doing wrong?

Now i am a bit of a rookie so this might look like a total mess.

## **[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/Jf0ugeVbiE)**

Best Regards,
Robin.

Comment: What are you expecting in case of mobile ? the footer to be fixed or relative?

Comment: Well, the main goal is to have it at the bottom. Fixed was my solution. Is there maybe another one? Thanks in advance

Comment: nope glad that worked